# Are system packages installed into /usr allowed to be broken by source installations into /usr/local?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, fhs

My `/usr/bin/vlc` binary was broken after installing `vlc` from source into `/usr/local` prefix. Based on my experience installations into `/usr/local` didn't affect binaries `/usr/bin/[binary]`, but maybe that was just by accident.

Afaik the effect of a `/usr/local` installation might be (unstable) shared libraries which are loaded from there before the (stable) ones from `/usr/`. So, does Ubuntu force package maintainers to load dynamic libraries from `/usr/` only?

Resources like [hier manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/7/hier), [BLSF position on /usr/local vs /usr](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/introduction/position.html) and [FHS explanation of Debian](https://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/fhs/fhs-2.3.html#USRLOCALLOCALHIERARCHY) answers this question imo since it doesn't define interoperability between binaries in different prefixes.

This is not about the functioning of path lookup priorities (for binaries, shared libraries, ...) which is quite clear for me, but about their usage (constraints, definitions, (pseudo)-standards) in Ubuntu.

Comment: Is the version in `/usr/local` still installed or did you remove it again?

Comment: Removed it. I want to figure out how Ubuntu handles this issue and I'm not looking for a solution for the broken `vlc` binary. This might be off-topic because it requests an off-site resource, but I don't seem to figure this out otherwise.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question and removed my answer again.

Comment: Sorry for waisting your time, but it's quite hard to formulate. Your answer allowed my to specify my question.

Comment: By default /usr/local/* 'trumps' /usr/*  so if same name libraries or binaries exist in both locations the ones in /usr/local will be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Based on my experience installations into `/usr/local` didn't affect binaries `/usr/bin/[binary]`, but maybe that was just by accident.

You should hang out around Ask Ubuntu more often. :)

Using `sudo pip install`, which installs to `/usr/local`, breaking various Python applications is IME by far the most common Python problem I have seen here. If you installed a PyPi package that already had a system package present, it could break whatever was using the system package. Just a few weeks ago I had `apt-get`-installed `certbot` break due to a `pip`-installed `certbot` plugin.

Packages aren't supposed to officially install anything in `/usr/local` (exceptions like CA certificates, aside), since that is the system administrator's domain - but that's the only restriction. Clearly if the system administrator is to make full use of the power that `/usr/local` provides, then things elsewhere in `/usr` must be able to be affected them. It's not so much that they're "allowed to be broken" by source install; it's more that the system administrator is trusted to know what effects their installing things in `/usr/local` will have.